# show like button of facebook on asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to use below code in my asp.net but i am getting error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('<%= fb-root.ClientID %>').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

i am getting error getElementById as it shows error that fb doesn't exist.
i have a div with id as fb-root.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that div?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `<div>` with ID `fb-root` has `runat="server"`?

If not, `ClientID` won't work, just use `getElementById('fb-root');`

If yes, try viewing source of the page to see what kind of ID you get for your script. It's also helpful to check for null reference to avoid errors, like this:

```
var divFBRoot  = document.getElementById('fb-root');

if( String(divFBRoot) != 'undefined' )
{
   //do your things
}
```

Comment: initially i had written with clientid but it showing error as null value. so i wrote clientId and my div doesn't have runat="server".

Comment: if you don't have runat="server", try using assigning an id to your div and address it in getElementById() by that ID. For example: <div id="fb-root">...</div> ...then document.getElementByid('fb-root')